# RVM installation: `/usr/local/rvm': Permission denied

Tags: ruby, rvm

```
demas@demas:~$ sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm

demas@demas:~$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    218      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   308
100 13145  100 13145    0     0  12150      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 12150
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm': Permission denied
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: `sudo mkdir /usr/local/rvm; sudo chmod a+xwr /usr/local/rvm`

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. Can you please create an Answer so I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a quick variant of eliminating this problem you can create `rvm` directory and allow everyone to write to it:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/rvm; sudo chmod a+xwr /usr/local/rvm
```

Comment: I installed rvm as root, and `sudo chmod -R a+xwr /usr/local/rvm` worked for me - i just added the recursive flag as it was already there. Thanks!

Comment: This is it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

you need to clean shell environment variables before start new installation, th easiest way is to logout and login again.

Answer (score 1):

I added the `sudo` on the right side of the '|' before the bash` and it seems to work:

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s -- --version latest**
```

Result: Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.26.10.tar.gz
Downloading